# Apply style in pyqt5 QTableWidget:selected

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have this simple app:

**file: untitled.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(1160, 574)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.player_list_table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Dialog)
        self.player_list_table.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 850))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 120, 215))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 255, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 120, 215))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 255, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 120, 215))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(170, 255, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.AlternateBase, brush)
        self.player_list_table.setPalette(palette)
        self.player_list_table.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.player_list_table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.player_list_table.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.player_list_table.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.player_list_table.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.player_list_table.setRowCount(20)
        self.player_list_table.setObjectName("player_list_table")
        self.player_list_table.setColumnCount(2)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.player_list_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.player_list_table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.player_list_table.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.player_list_table.horizontalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.player_list_table.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(260)
        self.player_list_table.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.player_list_table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.player_list_table.verticalHeader().setHighlightSections(False)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.player_list_table, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.player_list_table.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.player_list_table.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Αλλαγή θέσης"))
        item = self.player_list_table.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Θέση αρχείου"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**file: main.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
from untitled import Ui_Dialog

class Main:
    
    def __init__(self):
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        Dialog.show()
        
        ui.player_list_table.setRowCount(0)
        for i in range(0,20):
            ui.player_list_table.insertRow(i)
            
            #Title
            title_item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("Title text")
            title_item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter | QtCore.Qt.Alignment(QtCore.Qt.TextWordWrap))
            ui.player_list_table.setItem(i,0,title_item)
            
            #Image
            image_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
            image_frame.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\nborder:none;background:transparent;\n}")
            gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(image_frame)
            image_title = QtWidgets.QLabel(image_frame)
            sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
            sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
            sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(image_title.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
            image_title.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
            image_title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            image_title.setWordWrap(True)
            image_title.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\nborder:none;background:transparent;\n}")
            gridLayout.addWidget(image_title, 1, 0, 1, 3)
            image = QtWidgets.QLabel(image_frame)
            sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
            sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
            sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(image.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
            image.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
            image.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
            image.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(150, 150))
            image.setText("")
            image.setScaledContents(True)
            gridLayout.addWidget(image, 0, 1, 1, 1)
            spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
            gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 0, 2, 1, 1)
            spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
            gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

            image_title.setText("Image title text")
            
            ui.player_list_table.setCellWidget(i,1,image_frame)

        ui.player_list_table.resizeRowsToContents()
        ui.player_list_table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        
        ui.player_list_table.selectRow(0)
        
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    main = Main()
```

The problem is that when i run: `python main.py` and then highlight a row, the text color in the first column be white, but the text color in the second column be black. :/

What qss selector may i use for this situation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used the [currentCellChanged signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#currentCellChanged) to find which row is selected. Then when this signal is emitted then i change the qss of image title Label.

Comment: Can you please add more insight on your answer? Right not it's not clear what you did and there's no explanation on *why*. Also, there's no need to post *again* a file that is left unchanged, nor the *whole* modified file if the modifications are only about a few lines.

Comment: @musicamante i edit the answer.

Comment: @ChrisP The most accurate answer is always the best. Accurate is not minimal but not much, the idea is that with the necessary information any user can understand how to apply the solution, if possible also explain the cause, but if you launch a lot of code you only confuse us

Comment: @ChrisP sorry but your edit is not very helpful (and as you can see that's not just my opinion). I believe you've already seen a lot of examples of good answers, which don't necessarily need to be incredibly long or extremely detailed, but should always be *exhaustive* and explain both the reason of the problem (if there was one) and how the solution works. In your current answer you only *tell* what method you're using, not *showing and explaining how* you're using it (nor why).